# ons-scroller scrolling elements outside UL after scroll is at bottom (Android 4.0.4)

Tags: html, scroll, html-lists, overriding, scroller

I have some issues finding the best way to fix elements on my page.
The problem is that after I scroll down chatbox, some elements start scrolling up more then the others, like that `<center>` element.
After that I have another unordered list and it scrolls good, overriding the `<center>` element.

```
 <ul id="conversationBox" class="ChatLog">
       <ons-scroller>
       </ons-scroller>
     </ul>
     <script>
       fillConversationBox();
     </script>
     <div data-role="content">
     <center class="topBar"><font class="txtMessages">Mensagens</font></center>
```

Comment: It looks like your question title is out of sync with the text in the question itself. The title is about the content of the <ul>, while the text complains about the <center>, is that right? Also, the title says "Android", so is this in an Android app, or is it a regular webpage that has problems on Android browsers only? Anyway, can you show the CSS for the `.content` and `.topBar` classes? That's probably where the issue is.

Comment: By the way, I don't always make pedantic remarks about <center> and <font>, but in this case, why? I mean, really, why? The <font> doesn't even do things like change color, size or family. Then, why?

Comment: .content is defined by JQM.